# changing color of multiple divs one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem changing the color of some divs one by one.
on page load i create a div which is filled with a square of 15x15 divs (class='feld')

All the divs i want to change have the class feld

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
create();
var delay = 1;
function create(){
    for (z = 1; z < 16; z++) {
            var zeile = jQuery('<div/>', {
                class: 'zeile',
                id: z,
                html: ""
            });
            $("#wortfeld").append(zeile);
            for (s = 1; s < 16; s++) {
            var div = jQuery('<div/>', {
                class: 'feld',
                id: s,
                html: ""
            });
            $(".zeile[id=" + z + "]").append(div);  
            };
        };
    };
$('.feld').each(function(){ 
        $(this).delay((delay++)*500).css("background-color","lightgoldenrodyellow");
    });
});
```

So my intention was to change the color of each .feld one by one. But it doesn't work the way i approached this. 
I also tried to do it this way:

```
    create(function(){
        $('.feld').each(function(){ 
            $(this).delay((delay++)*500).css("background-color","lightgoldenrodyellow");
    });
});
```

doesn't work either

here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="de">
 <head>
<link href="design_crossword.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crossword.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wortfeld">TEST</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Write your code in jsfiddle

Comment: add your html part please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, an unrelated issue but one that could cause problems:
You shouldn't use an ID more than once, give your `zeile` and `feld` items unique ID's.
You could also get some mileage with setTimeout, no need to involve .delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
create();
var delay = 1;
function create(){
    for (z = 1; z < 16; z++) {
        var zeile = jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'zeile',
            id: 'z'+z,
            html: ""
        });
        $("#wortfeld").append(zeile);
        for (s = 1; s < 16; s++) {
        var div = jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'feld',
            id: 'z'+z+'s'+s,
            html: ""
        });
        $("#z" + z).append(div);  
        };
    };
};
    $('.feld').each(function(){
        setTimeout(function(x){
        $(x).css("background-color","lightgoldenrodyellow");
    },(delay++)*500,this);
    });
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zvghpsw1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.delay(duration).css({})
```

This doesn't apply the css after the duration, but immediately.

You need to use [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gdjjroav/1/):

```
$('.feld').each(function(){ 
    $(this).delay((delay++)*500).queue(function(next){
        $(this).css("background-color","lightgoldenrodyellow");
        next();
    });
});
```