# Changing the background color of one class, one by one with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a particular `class` one by one with a `delay` and not everything simultaneously.

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: To confirm, you want to apply the green background color to the first item div, then remove it and apply to the second one, and so-on?

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351205/changing-color-of-multiple-divs-one-after-another)

Comment: Also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: @VanquishedWombat i've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/vbwtW/ and i tried it with an animation onhover, but i want it on page reload or w/e.

Comment: @ZacWebb No, i want to apply let's say another color red to all my divs but div 1 would be red first, after 1 second div2 would become red and so on.

Comment: @RinoRaj Thankyou for the links, i've tried some of those which didnt help me.

Comment: read my answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution by using set timeout with an incrementing value for the timeout

http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/woQPeE

```
$('.item').each(function(i, item) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    item.classList.add('item--colored')
  }, i * 250);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this fixed it =)

Comment: @Laurianti it seems nice, but this code is minimum. but thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: minimum of this? $('.item').asyncCss('backgroundColor', 'red') ?
ok

Answer (score 4):

The comments show solutions with JS. So I will complete this by adding a way to do it in CSS only with animations and delays:

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: black;
  animation: colorit 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
@keyframes colorit {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorit {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, im gonna try to process this in my javascript. and add the css dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
 asyncCss: function(a, b, c) {
     var args = arguments;
          return this.each(function(i) {
            var j = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                j.css.apply(j, args);
            }, i * 1000);

          });
        }
    });

function changeCssAsync() {
  $('.item').asyncCss({
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      width: '10px',
      height: '10px'
  });
}
```

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item"></div>

<div class="item"></div>

<div class="item"></div>

<div class="item"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="changeCssAsync()" value="Use me as .css() function" />
```